# Cauchy's Integral forumla problem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

We are asked to evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_{\gamma}^{} \frac{z}{(z+9)^{2}}$$

Where $\gamma$ is the region $\gamma(t) = 2i + 4e^{it}$

Not quite sure where to take it from here, I know there is a pole of order 2 at $z=-9$ but when trying to find the residue at this pole I end up with a 1. But as this residual point corresponds to a pole which is not in $\gamma$ then it can't be used. Implying by the residue theorem that the integral is 0.

Using the C.I.F $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z-a} = 2\pi if(a)$$
but I can't apply this here as $z=-9$ is not an element of $\gamma$

Is the entire integral just equal to zero?

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :**   Actually $\gamma:|z-2i|=4$. So $-9 \not \in \gamma$. That is $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{z}{(z+9)^2}$ is analytic in $\gamma$.

So what about Cauchys theorem ?

Comment: $f(z)$ analytic in $\gamma$ where $\gamma$ is a simply connected closed curve implies that the integral is equal to zero yes?

Comment: @AaronCurran The point is that your circle doesn't contain the pole at $z=-9$. By Cauchy's theorem the integral is zero.